# Strange interaction between Visual Basic controls and .NET controls

Tags: .net, winforms, vb6, winforms-interop

I have a VB6 form like this:

[image]

The form is composed of a classic ActiveX CommandButton and a .NET UserControl (specifically, a WinForm) containing 2 WinForm Buttons. The UserControl is, of course, COM visible and inserted in VB6 using the VBControlExtender in the following way:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim WinFormButtons  As VBControlExtender

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set WinFormButtons = Controls.Add("DemoInteropNet.UserControlTest", "WinFormButtons", Picture1)
    WinFormButtons.Visible = True
    WinFormButtons.Height = Picture1.Height
    WinFormButtons.Width = Picture1.Width
End Sub
```

Demo:

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX4tg.gif)

As you can see from the demo sample, the WinForm buttons work correctly until I interact with the VB6 button. From that moment on, they become completely blocked (as evidenced by the change in style), do not raise events, and do not do anything at all. The only way to "unblock" them is to double-click in the area where they are located.

Do you have any idea about the reason for this behavior?

Of course, I have already tried everything:

- Focus
- ZOrder
- Refresh
- Redraw
- Various Events
- Various Container methods
- etc. etc.

Comment: Without seeing any of the code for the VB6 controls it's really hard to say. Are you doing anything strange with mouse capture, or low-level with the `WndProc` handler?

Comment: What happens in the click events (or any other relevant events) for all the buttons?

Comment: The code is all there. Neither the form, nor the user control, nor any of the buttons do anything at all. It seems to be a basic behavior. In the end, I managed to solve it. It turned out that it is necessary to register a subkey of the registry key CLSID. Through this subkey, it is possible to identify the container and the content of the WinForm components, such as ActiveX controls. At that point, interacting with actual ActiveX components no longer leads to that anomalous behavior.
The CLSID SubKey is "Control"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/clsid-key-hklm

Comment: @FilippoNikos I suggest you post an answer with that information (and more detail if possible). Comments can easily be deleted. Good research!